# How to convert this JSON to show in HTML using jQuery.ajax and why 0 in end?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

PHP end of process looks like following:

```
$output = array(
            'inputUrl' => 'some_value',
            'title' => 'some_value',
            'slug' => 'some_value',
        );
echo json_encode( $output );
```

I get response like:

```
{"inputUrl":"some_value","title":"some_value","slug":"some_value"}0
```

AJAX is like:

```
jQuery.post(
    "ajax.php",
    { 'action': 'store', 'url': url },
    function(data) { alert(data); }
);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why that `0` comes up in the end of response?
2. I tried `JSON.parse(response);` but not working. How to part elements of the response array in `jQuery`?

Question 1 is solved by using `die()` after the `echo` or `wp_die()` in WordPress.

Can someone help me with Question 2?

Comment: is there any other echo in that file?

Comment: Make sure there is no other echo on the file .. it shouldn't

Comment: No other `echo` is there.

Comment: Or var_dump or print_r etc? And is this in a framework?

Comment: No. But `die()` solved the `0`. Can you tell me the reason, why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wp_die();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) at the end of the code to avoid `0` at the end in response.

```
$output = array(
            'inputUrl' => 'some_value',
            'title' => 'some_value',
            'slug' => 'some_value',
        );
echo json_encode( $output );
wp_die();
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked. But what could be the reason?

Comment: @Pranav i don't know much of wordpress but i don't think wp_die() is good idea.. it stops the script at that point

Comment: @NirjharLo : `Notice how the 'action' key's value 'my_action', defined in our JavaScript above, matches the latter half of the action 'wp_ajax_my_action' in our AJAX handler below. This is because it is used to call the server side PHP function through admin-ajax.php. If an action is not specified, admin-ajax.php will exit, and return 0 in the process.` ( from doc )

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI : it's suggested by WordPress (check here https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: @PranavCBalan That's a nice explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the `0` is gone `JSON.parse(response)` creates a data object.

Individual elements can be accessed like `response.inputUrl`